# Make a button appears in front of video youtube embed api

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, z-index, wmode

So here is the deal i want that the button comes first so the client can skip video to see website...

```
// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'fJaHtTJ_wkc',
        playerVars: {
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0 ,
        modestbranding: 1,
        wmode: "opaque"
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Gznb/880/

Can some1 help me pls?

Comment: don't see any button on the jsfiddle.

Comment: the button its behind of video and i want to make him to stay like this: but here i use iframe http://jsfiddle.net/oc59vcp8/ on my example "http://jsfiddle.net/7Gznb/880/" the button doesnt comes to the front of video!

Answer (score 0):

Found a link that may answer your question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx

You need to make functions to allocate commands for the video itself, and link it to buttons themselves.  For a button to skip a video, you need to make commands to be able to skip the video itself.

Comment: I dont know if u understand me right i will put here some example... but on this example i use iframe and so i can use z-index, but when i try same code on youtube api the index doesnt work! http://jsfiddle.net/oc59vcp8/